# Can I use these Libertine glyphs in pdftex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontspec, libertine

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\ifXeTeX \addfontfeatures{Variant=01} \fi
ÖÜ
\end{document}
```

If you compile this with XeLaTeX, you get a different looking Ö and Ü character. It is very nice from the creators of Libertine that they included this alternate version that does not look weird for Hungarian eyes. Is there a way to use this in PDFLaTeX as the default Ö and Ü?

Comment: You should create an alternative set of `.pfb` files with accompanying `.tfm` and `.vf` files that use the glyph `Odieresis.alt` and `Udieresis.alt` instead of `Odieresis` and `Udieresis`. Such a conversion can be done with `otftotfm`.

Comment: @egreg So there is no "paste this into your preamble" hackery solution. Well then, I'm going for XeLaTeX.

Comment: No, unless you convince Bob Tennent to add a new variant besides `tlf`, `tos` and so on, where `otftotfm` uses the `ss01` feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should create a new font set with `otftotfm`; as a proof of concept, I tried to do

```
otftotfm -e texnansx --no-updmap --coding-scheme='EXTENDED TEX FONT ENCODING - LATIN' --feature=kern --feature=liga --feature=lnum --feature=tnum --feature=ss01 LinLibertine_R.otf LinLibertineT-tlf-t1
```

and received as output the line

```
LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base LinLibertineO "AutoEnc_l6dd3wk7q223pbmgrvq427ywmd ReEncodeFont" <[a_l6dd3w.enc <LinLibertineO.pfb
```

that I added as argument to `\pdfmapline` in the test file. The difference with the original call made by Bob Tennent (this can be found in the `.enc` file generated by `otftotfm` and read during a run of `pdflatex`) is that I added the option `--feature=ss01`.

Here's the test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapline{LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base LinLibertineO "AutoEnc_l6dd3wk7q223pbmgrvq427ywmd ReEncodeFont" <[a_l6dd3w.enc <LinLibertineO.pfb}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\ifXeTeX \addfontfeatures{Variant=01} \fi
ÖÜ
\end{document}
```

I ran this in the directory where the various fonts had been created. Here's the output.

[image]

Of course this would overwrite the files in the distribution, so a whole new font family should be created (changing `-tlf-` in the name or something like it) with a suitable style file and so on. What I did for the upright font should be repeated for the other fonts of the family.

Definitely not for the faint of heart. Use XeLaTeX.